# Trying to fit two divs inside a div container

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to have two divs inside a container but they're position really weird.

```
<div id="headernav">
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <nav id="navbar"></nav>
 </div>
```

I'd like the nav to be a specific width like 700px and the logo div to fit the remaining space so I put it at 100%

```
#headernav{
    background:#0000FF;
    height: 60px;
}
#logo{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
}
#navbar{
    width:700px;
    height:100%;
    background: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `calc(100% - 700px);` for logo `width`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc

take a look at this. works fine in chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/W5stS/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` and `table` and `table-layout: fixed` to have 2 blocks in the same row with same height, one with a fixed width and the other occupying the remaining width of the parent.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TpFjD/
Compatibility: IE8+ (you've to use the same fallback as for `inline-block` if you support IE7 and IE6)

```
<div id="headernav">
    <div id="logo"> A </div>
    <nav id="navbar"> B </nav>
</div>
```

/\

```
#headernav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background:#0000FF;
    height: 60px;
}
#logo {
    display: table-cell;
    background:red;
}
#navbar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 700px;
    background: cyan;
}
```

*If* the fixed width had been on the first block, you could've floated it (right or left) and use `overflow: hidden` on the second block. Even IE6 is compatible with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cal(100% - 700px);` in `#logo`, then your and `display: inline-block` to show two columns, the code could be this way:

Styles:

```
#headernav{
        background:#0000FF;
        height: 60px;
        font-size: 0; //this added
    }

    //New properties added
    #logo,#navbar{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    #logo{
        font-size: 1rem; //this added
        width: calc(100% - 700px); //this added

        background:red;
        height: 60px;
    }
    #navbar{
        font-size: 1rem; //this added

        width:700px;
        height: 60px;
        background: cyan;
    }
```